# Modern SharePoint client side webpart code repo

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I am wondering, if the OOB SharePoint Client Side webparts are open source or not? Let me give you a background, why I came to this point. I created a MS Flow manually triggered, added Column Formatting in one of list, and use `executeFlow` attribute to trigger the MS Flow. Everything looks good till this point.

Now I added this list view to a Page using OOB `List (preview)` client side webpart. The column formatting stays as is and on UI everything is as expected. But when I click the button created via Column Formatting on the page, nothing happens.

Since I have urgent need of rolling out my feature, I need the capability to trigger MSFlow from `List (preview)` webpart too. I cant wait until MS rollout this feature. So I thought to check [SharePoint Github](https://github.com/sharePoint/) repo. I scanned most of the repo, but couldnt find a repo which have these webpart available.

I dont want to build the webpart from scratch, just need some enhancement on top of the what we already have (available OOB). So I was, if these webpart are Open Soruce or not, and if so, where I can find them.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in webparts to SharePoint are not open source.

Comment: Do you have understanding of build-in features? Specifically, around list view? Actually I was playing with SPO a little bit, and identified that any view page in list (for e.g. AllItems.aspx) still uses the OOB Classic List View Webpart (i.e. XsltListViewWebPart). And on top of it, a SPFx extension (my wild guess) convert this classic view to modern view. So I was wondering, if I can do something similar. Like create a modern page, but add this classic list view webpart and get all the modern feature on my page?

Comment: You can't embed classic resources on modern pages -- it'll convert the page back to classic. The embedded list/doc webparts do have issues, such as the contextual menu not being complete (e.g. no Details), anything that interacts with a slide-out panel doesn't work, etc. Hopefully Microsoft will improve upon that.

Comment: But somehow, OOB List View Page is doing the same, having a classic web part, while rendering completely on modern UI. Anyways, I'll try to figure out some workaround. Thanks for the help, now at least I know its not open source.